# Pass parameter/property from publish profile to csproj file

Tags: asp.net-core, msbuild

I exclude some folders while building for development in .csproj file.

```
<ItemGroup>
<Content Remove="Production\**" />
<Compile Remove="Production\**" />
</ItemGroup>
```

I want to include those folders back in a "publish profile" but it does not work.

```
<ItemGroup>
<Content Include="Production\**" />
<Compile Include="Production\**" />
</ItemGroup>
```

So, how could i pass parameters from "publish profile" to build(.csproj) and prevent exclusion of those folders or include them back.

```
<ItemGroup Condition="'$(SOMEPARAM)'!='Production'">
<Content Remove="Production\**" />
<Compile Remove="Production\**" />
</ItemGroup>
```

So, i need to determine when build runs with "publish profile" in .csproj file and take according action.

I know it is possible with command line parameters but i want to use Visual Studio, not command line.

```
dotnet build /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile=FolderProfile;SOMEPARAM=Production
```

**Update:(Solution)**
Check my answer below, it works fine when CopyToPublishDirectory used.

**Update:(Another Solution)**
Alternatively, when targets specified with same names, a target from publish file will override the target from project file so we could define what to include/exclude separately in project and publish files.

Comment: The publish profile and the .csproj file are two separate files. If you exclude something from the project by removing it from the .csproj then the publish profile won't be able to see it.

Comment: why do you need to exclude folder while building? If you just want to have different content of build output and publish folders, you may play with `CopyToOutputDirectory` and `CopyToPublishDirectory` parameters

Comment: Set, they are not just contents, they need to be compiled and when not excluded they cause conflicts at compilation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, i determined that those includes need CopyToPublishDirectory. So following works fine too.
In .csproj file;

```
<ItemGroup>
<Content Remove="Production\**" />
<Compile Remove="Production\**" />
</ItemGroup>
```

In publish profile;

```
<ItemGroup>
<Content Include="Production\**" CopyToPublishDirectory="PreserveNewest" />
<Compile Include="Production\**" CopyToPublishDirectory="PreserveNewest" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can define any property inside a `<PropertyGroup>` in the publish profile and use it in a condition in the csproj's `<ItemGroup>`s.

This works beause the publish profile is imported into the project and msbuild evaluates all static property groups before all item groups, which means that even a file that is imported at the end of it can affect item groups logically above it.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes my projects have "similar" code but hard-coded limitations like features supported by the operating system or license features.

I have solved it using 2 "configurations", let me walk you through it

Step 1. define your compiler directive in a central location where you need it in your code like so:

```
Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");

#if IDPSH1
Console.WriteLine("IDPS H 1");
#elif IDPSH3
Console.WriteLine("IDPS H 2");
#elif IDPSH5
Console.WriteLine("IDPS H 3");
#endif

Console.ReadKey();
```

Step 2, in your build process, generate a build that would tell the compiler to generate **what you** need **where you need it**

```
dotnet publish ConsoleDefineConstants.csproj --output bin\release\IDPS-H-1 --configuration Release /p:DefineConstants=IDPSH1
dotnet publish ConsoleDefineConstants.csproj --output bin\release\IDPS-H-2 --configuration Release /p:DefineConstants=IDPSH2
dotnet publish ConsoleDefineConstants.csproj --output bin\release\IDPS-H-3 --configuration Release /p:DefineConstants=IDPSH3
```

In the sample, I instruct dotnet to build and publish

1. the relative project ConsoleDefineConstants.csproj
2. in release mode
3. using a compiler constant using the **/p:DefineConstants=**
4. in a location where my deployment packaging expects it

if I start the sample, I get
[image: the following result]

I added all the code you need in the sample, let me know if you like me to clarify something